# How to change subdomain in requests test with Rspec (for API testing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a question which is really specific. 
I don't want to do a controller test but a requests test. And I don't want to use Capybara because I don't want to test user interaction but only response statuses.

I have the following test under spec/requests/api/garage_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Garages" do

  describe "index" do
    it "should return status 200" do
      get 'http://api.localhost.dev/garages'
      response.status.should be(200)
      response.body.should_not be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

This works. But as I have to do more tests.. is there any way to avoid to repeat this? `http://api.localhost.dev`

I tried with `setup { host! 'api.localhost.dev' }` But it doesn't do anything. 
A `before(:each)` block setting `@request.host` to something, of course crashes because `@request` is nil before performing any http request.

The routes are set correctly (and in fact they work) in this way

```
namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
  resources :garages, only: :index
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a helper method in the `spec_helper.rb`, something like:

```
def my_get path, *args
  get "http://api.localhost.dev/#{path}", *args
end
```

And its usage will be:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Garages" do

  describe "index" do
    it "should return status 200" do
      my_get 'garages'
      response.status.should be(200)
      response.body.should_not be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting idea. But in this way every action should have its own helper. I could end writing more code than the the one I want to dry!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

## spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :api) do |example|
    host! 'api.example.com'
  end
end
```

## your spec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Garages", type: :api do

  describe "index" do
    it "should return status 200" do
      get 'garages'
      response.status.should be(200)
      response.body.should_not be_empty
    end
  end
end
```